# Huge spaces instead of regular spaces are pasted

Tags: html, string, excel, fonts, php-5.6

Given a string out of a copy from an Excel row.

I need the user to be able to copy/paste a row from Excel into a form. The given string is then passed into explode() in PHP so I have access to the different cell values.

Problem is : when I paste the given line into an input field, the values are separated by "huge" spaces (so PHP cannot explode by regular spaces). This is odd : when I paste the line into this actual Stackoverflow textarea or into my URL bar, regular spaces are pasted.

Since the Stackoverflow textarea shows regular spaces when I paste, please see below a link to a screencast showing my issue.

Video : http://recordit.co/NdrNSPeo4I
*.gif : http://g.recordit.co/NdrNSPeo4I.gif

Comment: Typically when copying from Excel the "text" representation has Tabs between the cell values in any given row, not spaces.  You should be splitting on Tab, not space.

Comment: No need to make a condescending remark about a user because they mistook tab spaces for "huge" spaces

Comment: You're irrelevant @actimel, there are various types of whitespace char. U+0009 is tab. Let's say U+000A, U+000B U+000C U+000D U+0020 U+0085 U+00A0 U+3000 and so on (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

Accessing data by `$values[i]`, this pattern will work:

```
$stringprocessed = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$string);
$values = explode(" ", $stringprocessed);
```